# extjs4.1 form reset with exclude some property

Tags: extjs4.1

I can reset a form by this way

```
   var form = Ext.getCmp('formId');
        form.getForm().reset();
```

but i want to reset my form exclude one `textfield`.

This textField name is `'name'`.

```
form.getForm().reset().exclude('name');
```

Is it possible.

Anyone help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every form field has `reset` method. So you can query for all fields but the "name" one and perform `reset` on each queried field:

```js
// the following query will search for all form fields
// and will exclude fields that have field name set to "name"
var fields = form.query('[isFormField][name!="name"]');

for (var i = 0, len = fields.length; i < len; i++) {
    fields[i].reset();
}
```

Check out [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/mhFTQ/).